# how to fix 'invalid argument' for ioctl requests to block device

Tags: c, ioctl, scsi

I'm writing a small c program to make tape status and seek requests via

```
        ioctl(int fd, long int request, &io_buf)
```

but after trial and plenty of error, ioctl is returning `-1` with the errno message "Invalid Argument"

I'm on Linux and running my program as sudo. The device I want to issue requests to is an optical drive, connected via SCSI. I've tried tape status and seek requests by passing requests (`MTIOCGET` or `MTIOCTOP`, respectively) to `ioctl`.

Code snippet for tape status function where fd is the file descriptor of the device returned by open() and mtgetbuf is an instance of the mtget struct from `sys/mtio.h`

```
       stat = ioctl(fd, MTIOCGET, &mtgetbuf);
       if (stat == -1)
       {
          perror("error on ioctl MTIOCGET request: ")
          return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }
```

Similar code snippet for seek tape function except `mtopbuf` is an instance of the mtop structure and MTSEEK is the defined op code for the seek operation, also in `sys/mtio.h`

```
        mtopbuf.mt_op = MTSEEK;
        stat = ioctl(fd, MTIOCTOP, &mtopbuf);
        if (stat == -1)
        {
           perror("error on ioctl MTIOCGET request: ")
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
```

Instead of invalid argument error messages and a return of -1, I would have expected a successful return from ioctl and the respective structure instances, mtgetbuf and mtopbuf, to have their members populated with data provided by the device.

I.e. A successful `ioctl()` command with the `MTIOCGET` request would return into the mtgetbuf mt_type member a value of either `MT_ISSCSI1`, `MT_ISSCSI2`, or `MT_ISUNKNOWN` (I don't believe it is any of the other defined values for other vendor-specific devices).

Note: I'm aware of the `linux/mtio.h` header file and I have tried including that in place of `sys/mtio.h` but the outcome is the same.

Comment: Make sure to `man st` and read it in detail.  You'll want to call `MTNOP` before your call to `MTIOCGET`.  Also, post the code for how you opened the device, and include the entries from `/dev` that you're using.

Comment: thanks @MikeAndrews. Reading the man page for `st` and will try by making the `MTNOP` call prior. I actually had some success using the SCSI Generic Linux driver via `<scsi/sg.h>`. I'm able to issue a successful INQUIRY command via `ioctl(fd, SG_IO, &io_hdr)` where `io_hdr` is an instance of `sg_io_hdr_t` found in `<scsi/sg.h>`. Will post code update when I have future success with the seek 6 or 10 byte command using either this strategy or going back to  `linux/mtio.h`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently had success issuing requests to a block device using the SCSI Generic Linux driver (SG). There are three header files (below) that have provided op codes, structures used to pass and retrieve data from the device, among other information.

SCSI SG Header files:

```
        /usr/include/scsi/scsi.h
        /usr/include/scsi/scsi_ioctl.h
        /usr/include/scsi/sg.h
```

A combination of online resources were instrumental in understanding how to package, send, and receive requests:

1) The TLDP SCSI Generic (sg) HOW-TO guide is a font of information on communicating to SCSI devices via the SG driver. A link to it is provided [here](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SCSI-Generic-HOWTO/index.html). It explains in detail various commands that can be issued, how to package the commands by creating an instance of the sg_io_hdr_t structure, as well as a [programming example](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SCSI-Generic-HOWTO/pexample.html) to send a SCSI INQUIRY command which returns basic vendor information of the device. There are also status and sense codes for error handling and understanding unsuccessful SCSI requests.

2) Seagate's SCSI Command Reference Manual was helpful at times to understand the structure of bytes/bits in a SCSI command. Typically the op code occupied the first byte and the remaining bytes were zeros. The op codes in this reference manual were defined between those three header files mentioned above.

I have been able to send successful INQUIRY and GET_SG_VERSION_NUMBER requests and most likely have been able to send SEEK(6), READ_CAPACITY(10), and REZERO_UNIT commands. I say most likely because -1/errno values are not being returned and no information is being passed back into the sense buffer which is an indication of warnings/errors (either SCSI, host adapter, or driver status codes).

Hope this answers OPs question.